# Matlab - Transforming my program into a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I wrote a code that: imports sequential files containing x- and y- columns, plots the data, fits the peaks using a 4-term gaussian, saves the plots as .png image files and finally exports all the variables into a table (called final). I want this program to be user friendly as non-programmers need to use it. Please let me know if it is possible. I would like to be directed towards the right path. As I do not know where to start.

There are thousands of resources on-line, but they are not specific. I would like to know if it is possible in my case to create a GUI, so I dont fish in an empty pond.

Comment: I think it's possible, but the question is very general for this forum.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to be directed to towards the right path. As I do not know where to start.

Comment: Well, this task is what I'm facing right now. I'd recommend to draw an image of the resulting GUI and start a new project from scratch. Slowly adding new features.

Comment: @Crowley thank you for sharing your method, I will follow it.

Comment: @Mosawi You can start with `doc uicontrol` and with anonymous functions. If in trouble ask question focused on that particular trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using "GUIDE" which is Matlab's GUI design environment. It's fairly easy to use. To start simply type:

```
guide
```

in the command window. There is a lot of documentation on how to make a gui with guide. I'd wager you could quickly come up with a gui that calls your script, or you could convert your script to a set of functions and call those from the gui.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html